# What's the best way to learn WebGL

Tags: webgl

It seems that a lot of the resources on WebGL training are scattered. Is there any definitive resource or training that anyone has found particularly helpful?

Thanks.

Comment: To be honest I think I'd start with OpenGL and move from there via OpenGL ES.

Comment: OpenGL ES 2.0 have the same shader language as WebGL so you can pick any good book on OGL ES 2.0 and learn WebGL shading language. But its suboptimal solution, hence its in comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could also check out this one:

[webGL: introduction](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=me3BviH3nZc)

Answer (score 6):

This site seems to be the go to site to begin learning with examples and has many links to other resources such as the webgl cookbook with code examples.

[Learning WebGL](http://learningwebgl.com/)

Do you have any background in graphics programming?

Comment: Afterwards I would start looking for a WebGL library to make my life easier (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7340263/opengl-and-webgl/7946175#7946175).

Comment: learningwebgl.com isn't good because it doesn't start by teaching you theory of how the Matrices work before starting to use them. It leaves you scratching your head. I want to know EVERYTHING, the bare metal, from scratch, including all the math involved to make it work, not just what pre-built functions to use.

Comment: You need to learn linear/matrix algebra. Check out https://www.khanacademy.org. They have some info on it. Most colleges dedicate a course to this topic. It takes some time to grasp all of the underlying mathematics involved. After learning that you will then need to learn domain-specific techniques (Computer Graphics) such as interpolation of lines, the rendering pipeline, how light calculations are done, etc... to understand it all. Be prepared to invest a lot of time.